# gain & offset values for Planet's PSScene4Band analytic_sr

Tags: planet

I can't find it in their docs nor their website, but basically I want to convert the pixel values (16-bit uint) to decimal for further computation.

A natural gain might be `1 / 65,535`, but I have a scene of a green field in May with max values of approximately 2000 for the visible bands, which would yield a reflectance of 0.03, which seems way too low.

Comment: This whitepaper on their surface reflectance product might be helpful:  https://assets.planet.com/marketing/PDF/Planet_Surface_Reflectance_Technical_White_Paper.pdf; it indicates the values are scaled by 10,000.

Comment: @smiller Right you are.  If you want to turn that into an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This whitepaper on Planet's Surface Reflectance product might be helpful: https://assets.planet.com/marketing/PDF/Planet_Surface_Reflectance_Technical_White_Paper.pdf.  It indicates the SR values are scaled by 10,000.